# Error when trying to dry up this react code (jsx)

Tags: reactjs, dry, jsx

This is a react project and the code below is jsx.  Code I'm trying to dry up below.  It works fine but it's long!

```
const rightIcons = (
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <FontIcon
                        className="material-icons"
                        style={iconStyles}
                        onClick={() => this.props.scrollCallback('frontend')}
                    >
                        important_devices
                    </FontIcon>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <FontIcon
                        className="material-icons"
                        style={iconStyles}
                        onClick={() => this.props.scrollCallback('backend')}
                    >
                        dns
                    </FontIcon>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <FontIcon
                        className="material-icons"
                        style={iconStyles}
                        onClick={() => this.props.scrollCallback('withCare')}
                    >
                        favorite
                    </FontIcon>
                </a>
        ...
            </div>
        );
```

this is my attempt at looping through it

```
const iconFields = [
        { icon: 'important_devices', component: 'frontend' },
        { icon: 'dns', component: 'backend' },
        { icon: 'favorite', component: 'withCare' },
        { icon: 'code', component: 'projects' },
        { icon: 'face', component: 'contact' }
    ];
{iconFields.map(function(icon, i) {
                    return (
                        <a href="#" key={i}>
                            <FontIcon
                                className="material-icons"
                                style={iconStyles}
                                onClick={() => this.props.scrollCallback(icon.component)}
                            >
                                {icon.icon}
                            </FontIcon>
                        </a>
                    );
                })}
```

I've tried the "icon.component" a few different ways but it always causes an error.  The "icon.icon" is working fine

Comment: In first code snippet you are passing component as string like `this.props.scrollCallback('backend')` and in looped code you are passing component as object. So change that to `this.props.scrollCallback(icon.component)}`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined>

Comment: onClick={() => this.props.scrollCallback(icon.component)}

Comment: If try and pass it a string at all when inside the .map it no longer works

Comment: yet a string works fine in the code above

Comment: Try changing `iconFields.map(function(icon, i) {` to `iconFields.map((icon, i) =>  {`

Comment: Can you add your entire code in question.

Comment: Yes Prakash sharma!  That did the trick.  I now have access to 'icon.component'.  Thank you for your time and patience.  I continue to be amazed at how willing people are to deal with newbs like myself on this site :)  Will hopefully have the knowledge to give back in the same way one day soon.

Answer (score 0):

final code for anyone with a similar issue.  Thanks to Prakash sharma!

```
const iconFields = [
            { icon: 'important_devices', component: 'frontend' },
            { icon: 'dns', component: 'backend' },
            { icon: 'favorite', component: 'withCare' },
            { icon: 'code', component: 'projects' },
            { icon: 'face', component: 'contact' }
        ];
        const rightIcons = (
            <div>
                {iconFields.map((icon, i) => {
                    return (
                        <a href="#" key={i}>
                            <FontIcon
                                className="material-icons"
                                style={iconStyles}
                                onClick={() => this.props.scrollCallback(icon.component)}
                            >
                                {icon.icon}
                            </FontIcon>
                        </a>
                    );
                })}
```